# How to avoid potentially expensive re-calculating of computed properties with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

Say I have `animals` in a redux store. It's a normalized object, the key is the `id` and the value is the object itself. Each animal has a key `is_dog`.

```
animals: {
    'id1': { location: 'foo', is_dog: true, name: 'Dog1' },
    'id2': { location: 'foo', is_dog: false, name: 'Cat1' },
    'id3': { location: 'foo', is_dog: false, name: 'Cat2' },
    'id4': { location: 'foo', is_dog: true, name: 'Dog2' },
}
```

I have a `DogsList` connected react component that looks at the store state and passes in an array of `dogIds` to the UI component. Calculation of `dogIds` is something like:

`dogIds = _.chain(state.animals).filter('is_dog').map('id').value();`

In the example above this would return `['id1', 'id4']`.

However, let's assume I have thousands of animals, and each animal has other properties that change frequently, say `currentLocation`, `lastFed`, etc. I know that `dogIds` will only change if `is_dog` changes for any animal, but I'm not quite sure how to not do the filter and map calculations unnecessarily on every change to any animal. I tried using `reselect` but I don't think it really helps in this case.

I'm leaning towards storing `dogIds` in redux proper, and manually updating it only when relevant. Like when a new dog is added to `animals`, or if a cat changes to a dog (my analogy is falling apart here). But I feel like I'm doing something wrong by keeping computed properties in a redux store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could look into using React's lifecycle methods like `shouldComponentUpdate` - here you could assess whether `newDogIDs !== oldDogIDs` and then only do stuff if they are different.

Comment: Thanks, that's good feedback. What I was trying to avoid is the actual `filter` calculation, but the more I think about it the more it seems like that won't be too expensive unless I have millions of animals.

Comment: Thinking further, I think I may've misunderstood your question. From what it seems, you'll have to perform that calculation every time your list of animals updates, either way - otherwise you'll never know if a dog has became a cat, and so on.

Comment: I suppose if you are handling the actions for 1) adding/removing animals and 2) changing an animals type (from dog to cat), then you should know when you need to recalculate `dogsList` (if those actions haven't happened, there's no need)